# Convolution of sequences

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let for given real sequences  $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}, (b_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$,
$c_n:=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} a_k b_{n-k}$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$ be the convolution of sequences  $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$.

For classical convolution if one of two functions is in $L^p$, the second in $L^q$, where $1\leq p,q <\infty$ then their convolution $f*g$ is in $L^r$, where $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}-1$.
Is it some similar type theorem true for convolution of sequences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  True not only for $\mathbb Z$ but for for abelian (more generally unimodular) locally compact group.  (20.18) in Hewitt & Ross, *Abstract Harmonic Analysis*.